# play video from input stream in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, desktop

I am using Javafx, I have a Inputstream of video data. How can i play this video stream directly in video player?

Media class constructor takes String object only and The supplied URI must conform to RFC-2396 as required by java.net.URI. Only HTTP, FILE, and JAR URIs are supported.

I have H.264 ACC video stream.

Comment: @jewelsea I have  H.264 ACC video stream. Will it work for this also?

Comment: The point the other answer was trying to make is that JavaFX 8 can't play any kind of media from an InputStream, only from the supported http, file of jar protocol types.  You can play from a http live stream, but that is a different thing.  There is a feature request to get the JavaFX media system modified to allow playing from an input stream, but it has not been actioned yet.  So short answer is: you cannot do what you want directly.  You can indirectly save the entire stream to a file and play from that if you wish.